# unable to release application on target

Tags: build, shared-libraries, blackberry-10, cascade

I have two cascade project.

I build a shared library (.so) from one project and in another project I use this .so file.

To build this (.so) file, we use this following .pro file-

```
APP_NAME = XYZ

TEMPLATE = lib

TARGET = XYZ

CONFIG += qt warn_on debug_and_release cascades

LIBS   += -lpps -lscreen -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lfreetype -lpng -lbb -ljpeg -lbbdata -lbbsystem -lbbdevice -lsqlite3 -lbbutility

include(config.pri)
```

Now to add this (.so) file I follow this [knowledgebase](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development-Knowledge/How-to-use-a-third-party-shared-or-static-library-in-a-Cascades/ta-p/1886279).

Now the problem is I can not run my application using Device-Release on device both Q10 & Z10. The following error is promt from qnx compiler-

```
unable to release application on target
```

But Device-Debug & Simulator-Debug working fine.

The strange thing is If I build my application without (.so) file its working on Device-Release. So, I suspect that the problem inside (.so). May be building (.so) file have some problem.

I search a lot in google and try following things-

[change bar-descriptor](http://www.bbdevbalkan.com/home/2013/07/cascades-release-build-fails/)

[compiling library and resources](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/tools/compiling.html)

But its all not workout for me. Need your help badly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been able to get this to work. I believe it has something to do with the building of the Cascades zygote for the Device-Release build, but I haven't really looked into it too much.

On further consideration I decided to use static libraries. If you use shared object libraries, then all of the code included in the library must be on the device. This is very efficient for widely used libraries like the C standard library because many programs can like against them. For your own library though, you have to include the library with your program, so you will be including object code whether or not it actually gets called in your program. If the library eventually grows to a large size, and you only use a small part of it this gets wasteful. When you statically link to a library, only those object modules that are actually needed in your program get included.